# How can I fix my invalid resx file input?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, resx, resource-files

I added several existing files (from a VS 2008 Windows CE project) to a VS 2008 Winforms project. For many (but not all) of the forms, I get this err re: the *.resx files:

*Invalid Resx file. ResX input is not valid. Cannot find valid "resheader" tags for the ResX reader and writer type names.*

The *.resx files that are fine display like so when I 2-click them in the Solution Explorer:

[image]

...whereas those that won't compile with the err msg above display one thing if I 2-click the *.resx file in the Solution Explorer, to wit:

[image]

...but the error-invoking *.resx files show their code if I 2-click the line in the Error List, like so:

```
. . .
  <resheader name="resmimetype">
    <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
  </resheader>
  . . .
```

Note: The solution here [C# resx file error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390447/c-sharp-resx-file-error):  doesn't seem to apply to my situation, as the out-of-kilter / off-the-rails files already have this format:

```
<resheader name="resmimetype">
    <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
  </resheader>
```

Why are some resx files fine while the others prevent compilation? How can I massage/tweak them to get past the compile gauntlet?

Comment: Could you post the source of a complete file that is not working? And the properties that you can see in the visual basic editor?

Comment: If you want it to satisfy your own curiosity, I will, but I "bit the bullet" and created a new project to avoid those issues.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little surprised that you can have the $ sign in the resource name.

Comment: I don't know how that got there.

Comment: Did that help? Cause that is basically invalid.

Comment: No; that's one of the ones that are fine - no err msg for that file.