# Resource file error

Tags: compact-framework, resx, pocketpc

I have a resource file for a pocket PC.

```
<resheader name="resmimetype">
    <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
</resheader>


    <resheader name="version">
        <value>1.3</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="reader">
        <value>System.Windows.Forms.Design.CFResXResourceReader, System.CF.Design, Version=7.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="writer">
        <value>System.Windows.Forms.Design.CFResXResourceWriter, System.CF.Design, Version=7.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
    </resheader>
```

Invalid Resx file. ResX input is not valid. Cannot find valid "resheader" tags for the ResX reader and writer type names.

My system doesn't have the system.CF.Design namespace. I have installed the compact version of .net framework 3.5.

Can anyone help me with this issue.This is a high priority issue.

Comment: This question contains a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226794/how-can-i-resolve-the-invalid-resx-file-cannot-find-valid-resheader-tags-fo