# Invalid Resx file. ResX input is not valid. Cannot find valid "resheader" tags for the ResX reader and writer type names

Tags: c#, xml, file, resx

I have this resource file for checking and everytime I run the program it prints the error Invalid Resx file. ResX input is not valid. Cannot find valid "resheader" tags for the ResX reader and writer type names.

But I have the root and resheader elements in my file so what's wrong ?

```
<root>
  <resheader name="text1">
    <value>Hello</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="text2">
    <value>my</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="text3">
    <value>name</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="text4">
    <value>is</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="text5">
    <value>Jacob</value>
  </resheader>
</root>
```

Comment: This might be relevant, specially the Update 2 section of that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226794/how-can-i-resolve-the-invalid-resx-file-cannot-find-valid-resheader-tags-fo

Comment: I found that , but I don't understand , what did he mean by that ?